# In Django, is there a way to set field values with a query expression on objects returned from a queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, query-expressions

I have a proxy model which has to have some calculated (with query expressions) read-only fields. Annotating won't do, because I will later need to have field metadata to do filtering in my views.

So, is there a way to call a SQL function to get the value?

I am looking for something like a `QuerySet.annotate` for fields, a `Transform` or a custom field that would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this by using the [`Col` `Expression`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/expressions.py#L607) and a custom field.

Comment: @Florian not at all, I'll just have to remember how exactly I've done it.